# Angular build set target for chunked / transpiled files

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-builder

We are using angular 6.

I want to create another angular app and put in in the same domain, here is the example
`example.com` is the main app, my new app will be hosted on
`example.com/app2/`

Here is what my apache configuration looks like

```
<VirtualHost>

ServerName example.com

...

ProxyPass /app2/ http://app2-server:4200/
ReverseProxyPass /app2/ http://app2-server:4200/

ProxyPass / http://main-app-server:4200/
ReverseProxyPass / http://main-app-server:4200/

...

</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I try to access new app, it creates the problem to download files because
the angular app will insert following files in index.html
`main.js` `vendor.js` `styles.js` etc.

Now the request of `main.js` from `example.com/app2/` will go to `example.com/main.js` because angular build process automatically adds `main.js` in index.html

Is there a way to say angular that instead of adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.foo.js"></script>` my app needs to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="/app2/main.foo.js"></script>`

I understand this can be done on build process. But these are not the only files. There are chunk files which webpack refers and downloads dynamically. Those reference needs to change too.

Also developers use dev-server not build flow. So this path change needs to be part of dev-build too.

**So the question is, is there a way to set path of these auto generated files (including webpack chunks)?**

P.S.
I use angular 6 but app2 can be upgraded to angular 9/10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add

```
ng build --prod --base-href /app2/
```

Into your build command,
Or I’m pretty sure you can configure this in angular.json under build.options.baseHref

Regarding the dev server, I’m not sure why this would matter. So I’ll need more detail there on what you’re trying to accomplish. If you’re hoping to run two projects at once, that’s a different story as you can’t have two local servers listening on 4200.

Comment: Yes ofcourse two apps won't work on same port on dev machine. Those will be different port

Comment: Base href will use add `<base href="/app2/">` but the scripts will be `<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>`

So the main.js will always do `example.com/main.js` not `example.com/app2/main.js`

Comment: yes, the index generates relative routes, which is all you need it to do.  your understanding of how this will resolve is incorrect. it's requesting relative to `mydomain.com/app2/` at that point. I've deployed like this many times and tested again just for sanity. Your apache config looks pretty wrong. Are you trying to run your dev server in production for some reason?